# Ping/nslookup working but telnet/browser fails

Tags: networking, browser, ping, telnet, nslookup

Having a problem on several systems. Ping, nslookup and tracert all work as expected but the browser and other applications including telnet are unable to get any internet access. The problem is not consistent - it happens (seemingly) randomly and is solved by a router reboot. (I am looking for a solution to stop it happening in the first place).

Also, I am accessing these systems via Gotomypc - I'm not sure what protocol this uses but assuming its not TCP, I'm starting to think that TCP is somehow being blocked. Anyone agree? How do you go about confirming/resolving that?

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Thanks,
Tony.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like a mismatched port forwarding configuration. Since ping/nslookup/tracert all rely on ICMP, which is layer 3, they do not rely on a destination/source port to function.

Telnet and HTTP, however, reside in the application layer, and so they require those ports to function. A simple verification of whether this issue lay with the router or with the client machine configurations would be to connect an ethernet cable between two client machines and attempt some sort of layer 5 connectivity between them (through the use of an SSH server or an FTP server)

Please also verify that there is no current port forwarding, port triggering, port fingering, or DMZ configuration on your router.